# Unexplained results with VS2008 "Get everything..." option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

We've only recently begun using TFS (2008) with Visual Studio (2008). A couple of developers discovered the "Get everything when a solution or project is opened" option in VS and decided it was a good idea--and it would seem to be.

However, we've been getting some curious results when opening some solutions. The solutions in question contain several projects of mixed types--mostly class libraries and  web apps. The curious part is the list of files in the "Get" dialog box that comes up.

Here's what I've found out so far about the files in the list:

- The list is incomplete; not every controlled file in the solution is listed.
- The version in the workspace matches the version in source control.
- They are not missing from the workspace.
- There are files from each of the projects in the solution; though, not every file in each project is included.
- The list of files is the same for three seperate developers on three seperate machines.
- Running a **tf get** from a command line does not yeild the same results.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. As I mentioned, this option seems like a good idea, but we're a bit hesitant to rely on it when the results are unexpected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that any files that are not in any project will not be pulled down by TFS when you go to get a latest at the solution level. My guess is that is part of your mixed/unexpected results.

I personally do not have that option checked. I always pull everything down from source control first thing. Whenever I check in source code, I also pull down everything again, compile it and run it first. That way I do not introduce any issues into TFS.

I would make sure that everyone on your development team is using the same general settings for TFS source control. I always have it prompt for check out (saving/editing) and get latest version of item on check out.

Have you applied the latest SP for TFS 2008 (SP1 last I remember). And SP1 on each developer's machine as well?